# How does IServiceProvider constructor injection work?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, winui-3

I have a small snippet of custom logic I want to execute when a dependency instance is created.

Say I have this constructor:

```
public ThisViewModel(AnotherViewModel anotherViewModel)
```

When an instance of `ThisViewModel` is created, the DI container must resolve `AnotherViewModel`, then pass that it into that constructor.

I need to execute a check against `AnotherViewModel` before it is injected into `ThisViewModel`, and the same check against `ThisViewModel` before it is returned.

I have put the logic I need into my `GetService<T>()` method, and that works well in places where I use that, however, most of my DI is constructor injection. But thus far I can't find out how it works under the hood to try to hook into the system somewhere and add that logic in.

Currently, I am registering my types by collecting all the Assembly types into an array, and passing that array through a set of methods, these methods extract a specific subset of types and register them according to requirements. An example of this is as follows.

```
private static void ConfigureViewModels(IServiceCollection services, Type[] types)
{
    var viewModels = GetTypesAssignableTo(typeof(IViewModel), types);

    foreach (var viewModel in viewModels)
        if (viewModel.IsAssignableTo(typeof(ISingletonViewModel)))
            services.AddSingleton(viewModel);
        else
            services.AddTransient(viewModel);
}
```

In this method, I get all the ViewModels based on the fact that they all extend from ViewModelBase, and ViewModelBase implements IViewModel. A few of them are required to be singletons, so they have another interface implementation of ISingletonViewModel, which is used soley for making this determination, and registering the type correctly, automatically.

What I'm trying to achieve here, is that when a registered type is instantiated, I want to check for the implementation of IHandle, and subscribe the instance to the events in the event broker...

Comment: You can register factories instead of just the type. How do you register them now?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of check you need to perform?

Comment: I've updated the original question to cover these questions - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Register the type(s) with an implementation factory and perform any custom logic in this one, e.g.:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient(serviceProvider =>
{
    // custom logic for resolving AnotherViewModel...
    return new AnotherViewModel();
});
builder.Services.AddTransient(serviceProvider =>
{
    // custom logic for resolving ThisViewModel...
    var anotherViewModel = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AnotherViewModel>();

    return new ThisViewModel(anotherViewModel);
});
```

Comment: I can see how this would work - but it would be VERY tedious/laborious, as I would have to do this for every type in my client application that handles messages from the event bus... I'm really hoping I can do something far more generic, such that whenever ANY instance is resolved from the container, it can check if it implements IHandle<T>, and if it does, subscribe the instance to the event bus messaging system

Comment: If you have to do something like that for each type in your application you obviously have at least one design flaw in your setup. It sounds like you need to rethink what you are doing and find a better way. Your original question should have been answered though.

Comment: I was able to rework what I already had to make it work.

Comment: I don't think it's so outside the realms of normal to subscribe handlers with the eventing system.. there could well be another way around it. I feel like handling it at resolution time with a simple " if (resolvedObject is IHandle handler) _eventBroker.Subscribe(handler); " far worse of an idea would be to have all the event handlers have a dependency on the event broker, and calling Subscribe(this) in the constructor...